# How to get the number of available cores in python

Tags: python, linux, multiprocessing, taskset

The standard method that I know to get number of cores in python is to use [multiprocess.cpu_count](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.cpu_count)

```py
import multiprocessing
print(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
```

Also, when creating a task we can specify some cores that the process can access using [taskset](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/taskset.1.html).

Apparently `cpu_count` is always getting the number of available cores of the machine, regardless if the process was restricted to use only some of those cores.

```bash
python nproc.py
taskset 7 python nproc.py
taskset 1 python nproc.py
```

[nproc](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nproc.1.html) on the other hand gives the number of cores available for the process.

```py
taskset 7 nproc # gives at most 3
taskset 1 nproc # gives 1
```

I know I could invoke `nproc` or `taskset -p {os.getpid()}` to get the correct number of cores. Is there another way to do this, without relying on other programs (reading
`/proc/{os.pid()}/*` could be a solution).

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the docs, this may be of limited availability, but it seems the `os` library has what you want;

> #### [Interface to the scheduler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#interface-to-the-scheduler)
>
> These functions control how a process is allocated CPU time by the operating system. They are only available on some Unix platforms. For more detailed information, consult your Unix manpages.
>
> New in version 3.3.
>
> ...
>
> **os.sched_getaffinity(pid)**
>
> Return the set of CPUs the process with PID pid (or the current process if zero) is restricted to.

tested using Ubuntu 20.04.2 (WSL):

```
aaron@DESKTOP:/mnt/c$ python3 -c "import os; print(os.sched_getaffinity(0))"
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11}
aaron@DESKTOP:/mnt/c$ taskset 7 python3 -c "import os; print(os.sched_getaffinity(0))"
{0, 1, 2}
```

Edit: on windows you'll probably have to look to [`psutil`](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.Process.cpu_affinity)